# Minimalistic, free project management site with tree-like task structure?

Tags: software

I'm looking for a project management site, that

- has a **free version**, that
- can be accessed by **multiple people**
- enables entering **tasks** for which
- you can add **any number of fields with values** (like "description", "name", etc - but the key is that I am able to define any number of new fields)
- you can add any number of **subtasks** to any number of depths (this is what I mean by tree-structure)
- and that can show the tasks in a **GANTT visualization** (so tasks have a specific start and end field)
- showing **which task is a subtask of which**
- and **which task depends on the completion of some other (and which) task**
- and possibly has the option to add **people** as well (e.g. to show who has which tasks).

I've been looking for a solution for this but so far I haven't found anything that would suffice these set of requirements. Is there a solution out there?

Comment: You could try asking on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. I think this question is a better fit on that community.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will do that!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Software Recommendations are off-topic in this community.

Answer (score 1):

While recognising that this community is not focused on software recommendations, I have used Team Gantt which seems to do most of what you are asking for - with the possible exception of user-defined fields, which I have not investigated. The developers are very approachable, at least when I asked a "how to do..." question, so they may be able to help with specific questions. I use the free version for a project for a small club rather than for a company so can't comment on the suitability or costs for companies or other types of organisations, with multiple users and multiple projects.